# Append Suffix using PowerShell and Regular Expression

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a string:

```
somestring = "someprefix_somefixedentry"
```

I want to replace this string to

```
somestring = "someprefix_somefixedentry_somesuffix"
```

How can this be easily achieved in PowerShell using *regular expressions*?

I have already tried the following:

```
$BaseVar = "somestring = `"someprefix_somefixedentry`""

$BaseVar -replace "somestring = `"someprefix_(\w)", "somestring = `"someprefix_(\1)_somesuffix"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the *regex* you are looking for:

```
$BaseVar -replace '(?<=somefixedentry)', '_somesuffix'
```

It uses a **positive lookbehind** to determine the *position* to insert the suffix.

Comment: Or making the second one more readable: `$somestring = "${somestring}_somesuffix"`

Comment: I want to keep my enclosing Quotation marks and want whats behind the equal sign in it.

Comment: Yes, I didn't read your question properly but edited my answer now.